# Identifying non-standard fastener/nut

Tags: fastener

I am trying to identify a nut/fastener that is a part of our children's bed:

[image: Foto of fastener complete]
[image: Foto of fastener split]

(Note I am not a native English speaker, so hope I got all the technical terms correctly, please tell me if it doesn't make sense)

The fastener looks a bit like some sort of cylindrical nut, but there is no thread inside the hole (it holds a smooth metal rod) and also a bolt attaches to the top (which holds the fastener in place). I tried looking through the "nuts" sections of a few online retailers, but couldn't find anything like it.

Does anyone have any ideas for a Google term that would let me find if somebody sells something like this? Or would I need to make this myself by drilling a hole into a cylindrical nut?

Comment: You could get close with a "knockdown cross barrel fastener", but you'd have to drill out the threading in the 'cross' part, and tap the top to take the machine screw. If you could sketch the use, we might be able to help suggest alternatives.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate thanks for the comment. I am aware of some alternatives (in particular, it did hold well quite some time with a piece of wood and duct tape :-) ), but wanted to try to get "the real thing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a barrel clamp and screw. There are a lot of them out there and in different sizes.... The one pictured below is from Belmetric.com which I'm not affiliated with in any way, shape or form.

[image]

Comment: Theirs looks like an 8-32 maybe 10-32  the example you give looks close to 1/4-20. The first number is the size the second is the thread pitch. Those are  national screw sized there are corse and fine There are metric there diameter in mm and the thread pitch 1 or 1.25 I am not as fimilar with metric but that should help get the correct size.

Comment: I did find this as "Barrel cable and screw" so I guess there is a typo? Anyway, thanks this look very promising!